# Changing my shell

Tags: command-line

This question has been asked before and I have read the answers, but they do not seem to work for me.

The simplest answer seems to be to use `chsh`.  Makes sense!

But when I do `sudo chsh -s tcsh rolf` I get a warning "tcsh does not exist".

Yet if I type `which tcsh` I get `/usr/bin/tcsh` and if I type `tcsh` at the command line I get a tcsh shell.

If I just do `sudo chsh rolf` I get an interactive result that indicates that `tcsh` already is my login shell.  Nevertheless whenever I log in, I  get a bash shell (until I take overt action by typing `tcsh`).

What can I do to get tcsh as my shell automatically?

(*Please* don't tell me that I should be using bash and not tcsh; that is not an issue which I am disposed to discuss.)

Comment: When you say "login" do you mean via remote connections, local TTY instances, or the gnome-terminal or similar GUI?

Comment: you need to use the full path /usr/bin/tcsh  or be in the /usr/bin directory to avoid that warning....

Comment: Also make sure that `/usr/bin/tcsh` appears in `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/tcsh rolf`, log off and log on again.

Also make sure that file `/etc/shells` contains a line `/usr/bin/tcsh`.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Not exactly intuitive though, is it? :-)

Comment: Well, `man chsh` does mention `/etc/shells`. Would you consider marking the answer as resolved then?